# Permanently hide column of Ext JS grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

ExtJS 5

I am using ExtJs 5 Grid. I have a button, when i click on it, age column will be hidden by using below line.

```
Ext.getCmp('grdSample').columnManager.columns[2].setVisible(false);
```

I am using **listener - beforecellclick**  just to get the index of clicked column. But when i click on last column (last column = next to hidden column) it still show original index of column. Hidden column still getting their position in grid.

In CSS - If we use visibility: hidden then it hides the component or tag but still take space in web page but if use display: none, it hides as well as it doesn't take space in web page.

I want hidden column should not take space while getting indexing of current clicked column. (Without using CSS).

Can anyone help me to sort this out.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var studentStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: ['Name', 'Age', 'Fee'],
        data: {
            items: [
                { "Name": 'Puneet', "Age": '25', "Fee": '1000' },
                { "Name": 'Ankit', "Age": '23', "Fee": '2000' },
                { "Name": 'Rahul', "Age": '24', "Fee": '3000' }
            ]
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

        var window = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'grdWindow',
        width: 400,
        title: 'Grid Samples',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'hide age column',
                        handler: function () {
                            Ext.getCmp('grdSample').columnManager.columns[2].setVisible(false);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'grid',
                        id: 'grdSample',
                        height: 300,
                        selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',
                        {
                        }),
                        store: studentStore,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                header: 'Name',
                                dataIndex: 'Name',
                            },
                            {
                                header: 'Age',
                                dataIndex: 'Age',
                            },
                            {
                                header: 'Fee',
                                dataIndex: 'Fee'
                            }
                        ],
                        listeners:{
                            beforecellclick: function (el, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                                debugger;
                            }
                        },
                            dockedItems:
                                [   
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                                        store:studentStore,
                                        dock:'bottom',
                                        displayInfo:true
                                    }
                                ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {text: "Name", flex : 1, dataIndex: 'Name'},
            {text: "Age", flex : 1, dataIndex: 'Age', id : 'colAge'},
            {text: "Fee", flex : 1, dataIndex: 'Fee'}
        ],
        listeners : {
             'cellclick' : function (me, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts ) {
                   me.panel.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(cellIndex).dataIndex)}} // here you get the correct value :)
    });
```

Here is working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/1623/

Comment: After hiding column, when click on last column (fee), it returns index 2. It should be 1.

Comment: Why do you need the index of the clicked column ?

Comment: Actually i just need the correct cell index. when i click on this column. I have many task to implement based on clicked column data index. Ex. when i will get correct cell index so that i can get correct data index of clicked column. Based on data index, i want to execute some code. If you can get correct data index of clicked column without getting cell index, then it would be much better.

Comment: @ Benoit Cuvelier  - Did you get what i want actually?

Comment: Yes I think, so what you really need is more Data Index than just the index of the column ?

Comment: Try this new Fiddle and tell me if it is what you looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/1619/

Comment: Thanks. It looks like correct. But i don't know why it was not working in my program. I will check again and give you fiddler. I will accept your answer tomorrow.

Comment: Nice :) I will modify my answer

Comment: Hello Benoit, I checked your last fiddler. It works proper in Ext JS 4.2.0. But when i run this in Ext JS 5.1.0 then it doesn't work. Can you please check it again.

Comment: i checked but not proper working in Extjs 5 and first time is correct after hide the column not show show header index,please try again.

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier - I have also checked, it's proper working in Ext JS 4.2 but it's not working in Ext Js 5.1. After changing Ext JS version from 4 to 5, It doesn't work. Can you please check again and If it's working then add snapshot.

Comment: Yes, It's working now. Nice efforts. I praise your efforts. Update answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an overkill, but you could create an array of your columns

```
var columns= [{dataIndex: 'Name', header: 'Name'}, { dataIndex:'Age', header: 
'Age' }, { dataIndex:'Fee', header: 'Fee'}]
```

2) then remove a column from array by index using javascript splice method
and reconfigure your grid

```
myGrid.reconfigure(myStore, columns);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i think, it's wrong way to solve it. Suppose if we hide and show column dynamically, then this logic will break and main thing is that professionally it's wrong to do this.